# Intellij compiler excludes for scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have added a Scala class to the excludes.  The result is correct: that class **is** excluded during compilation.

However, I would like to add that class back to compilation. Now that seems to be troublesome.

The IJ help says to navigate to

> File|Settings|Build,Execution,Deployment|Compiler|Excludes

Which shows they do not update their docs frequently: the correct path is:

> File|**Other** Settings|Build,Execution,Deployment|Compiler|Excludes

But even then, there is NOTHING in the excludes list:

[image]

So then, where *is* that list for Intellij 14?

Comment: If you want to manage this via sbt, rather than Intellij, see https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/simple-build-tool/zVMyoWRAVWg .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File | Other Settings | Default Settings is the settings for the default project, which is not at all what you need. The correct Settings dialog is invoked as IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences.